# How to produce citations in the following style

Tags: bibliographies

I am new to Latex and I am not familiar with the citation system. I need to write a paper in Latex that produces citations in the style in the figure.

A few things regarding this style:
[image]

There is no number before each citation. The author names of each citation have to be bold. Published year has to follow the author names

I have a template that I use. It can be downloaded here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_LJgXEFhuRGdDFsdU8xM2ZWWGM

Comment: Please be reminded that it is always much more helpful to give as much information as possible: what bibliography package are you using, for instance. Providing a fully working minimal example is very useful in this regard.

Comment: Sorry, I have a template. I revised the question adding the link to the template.

Comment: Then this question does not make any sense. The template is specifically designed for Usenix papers and comes with a `.bst` file. This `.bst` file will format citations and bibliographies as anticipated by Usenix (maybe not as your example above). So either you are writing an article for Usenix, then you should use their `.bst` file to stick to their requirements. Or you are writing literally anything else, then it makes no sense to use such a special template and you can for instance apply my answer below.

Comment: And by the way, even if you would use the Usenix template but not their `.bst` style for any weird reason. My answer is certainly fully compatible with this template otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not giving the faintest information what kind of bibliography package you are using, or any other information about your document or requierements at all, here is a solution with BibLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Lit.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{Lit.bib}
@ARTICLE{Aguilera-Franco:2001,
  author = {Noemi Aguilera-Franco and Ulises Hern\'{a}ndez-Romano and Peter A.
    Allison},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Biostratigraphy and Environmental Changes Across the {Cenomanian--Turonian}
    Boundary, Southern {Mexico}},
  journal = {Journal of South American Earth Sciences},
  volume = {14},
  number = {2},
  pages = {237--255},
  doi = {10.1016/S0895-9811(01)00014-1}
}
\end{filecontents}

%BibLaTeX setup
%Print author names in bold
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

%No space between initials
\renewcommand{\bibinitdelim}{}
%No full stop after initials
\renewcommand{\bibinitperiod}{}
%No comma between last name and first name/intials (in last-name--first-name order)
\renewcommand{\revsdnamepunct}{}

%Print all authors as Last name-first name (author-date system)
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

%Reformat separators for authors
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

%Remove fulstop after year
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}

%Remove qutotation marks from titles
\DeclareFieldFormat
    [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
    {title}{#1\isdot}

%Set journal and booktitles upright
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{booktitle}{#1}

%Remove "pp." only in journals page-ranges
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}

%Just remove "in" before journal articles, leave rest as is
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}%
}

%volume and issue as volume instead of volume.issue
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit*{\space}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

%colon plus space before pages in journals
\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit}

\begin{document}
Test \textcite{Aguilera-Franco:2001}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```